# Is it normal for training loss to plateau before decreasing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

Is this training loss graph normal - where it flattens for quite a while before dropping? This is something that I am seeing when I train my neural net every time.

[image]

Because whenever I read papers the training loss usually looks like this so it makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: there is no one way that a loss function "should" look. The way that a NN learns your data is something we basically don't understand. There is some interesting recent research that shows some weird loss function. For example, the "[double descent phenomenon](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/)" shows that loss will often hit a local minimum, increase, and then decrease to a lower minimum.

I've built some models that look like yours. One was because there was a strong local minimum at a really simple solution. So your model gets stuck there for awhile until it finds a more complex solution. This may not be what your model was doing, but I don't see any reason to worry about it.

Comment: Yes I think it might be the case because when the model is in it's "stuck" period it is predicting an output of 0.5 every time which is approximately the average of my training set - then it "learns" some more features and escapes the plateau and predicts different outputs.